# React Hooks - Using useRef without direct access to HTML Element Code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

With React I'm inside of one repository, and the HTML elements are loading from another repo, which I watch for using pageLoaded. Inside updateHeader there is just more HTML element selecting and attribute/class manipulation.

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (pageLoaded.status) {
            if (someCondition) {
                updateHeader(ubeName);
            } else {
                document.querySelector('.headerbar-menu').style.display = 'block';
                if (document.querySelector('.headerbar-menu.affiliates-wrapper')) {
                    document.querySelector('.headerbar-menu.affiliates-wrapper').style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        }
    }, [pageLoaded.status])
```

The problem here is obviously we shouldn't be using querySelector, and i think it may be causing some unexpected functionality. The elements dont properly evaluate and render until some piece of state changes i.e. a scroll state handler, so on initial page load the elements dont show with their new attributes until a scroll.

I'd like to attempt to resolve using useRef, but don't have direct access to the html. Is there a way to dynamically connect a ref to an element without access to the HTML code?

Thanks for your time and attention!

Comment: *the HTML elements are loading from another repo* - this fact will make any solution messy... Using a DOM selector may well be your best option here. They are generally not recommended, but that advice is usually referring to elements that React is trying to manage. I don't know that there's a way to use refs like this, and if so, it would probably be even more hacky than what you're already doing.

Comment: hmmm gotcha thanks brian i appreciate it. do you have any other ideas about my issue? i've tried to force a re-render by setting some state at the end of the html manipulation, yet the elements still dont show up unless i manipulate the page somehow

Comment: Try using useEffect and setting the state to watch accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this, in my opinion, is in this sequence:

1. Attempt to select the element
2. If non-existant, set up a `DOMSubtreeModified` event handler or a `MutationObserver`
3. Clean up `DOMSubtreeModified` event handler or a `MutationObserver` (or keep it around to watch for updates)

This allows for use of query selectors in a safe and modern way which doesn't stray too far from React's recommendations

Comment: thanks for the reply! we've figured out the issue and i believe it was a matter of race conditions. By placing the useEffect in a different hooks file which had higher priority than the one it was already in, it was able to render correctly. this is very informative however and i'll label it as a solution anyway since i'll likely use this when we're looking for a similar solution.